# Python 3.6 - find core pattern in two list

Tags: python, list

I am searching for an efficient way to find core patterns in two different lists, I'll explain:

List 1:

```
[10318, 6032,1518, 4061, 4380, 73160, 83607, 9202, 28812, 40359, 28457, 
 3292, 2678, 8492, 7149, 19417, 7372, 8534, 3889, 11123, 8415, 5989]
```

List 2:

```
[5760, 1541, 2085, 637,1518, 4061, 4380, 73160, 83607, 9202, 28812, 40359, 
 28457, 3292, 2678, 8492, 7149, 19417, 7372, 8534, 3889, 11123]
```

The two lists could have more than 300 elements, the similar elements in each list is statisticaly very large each time (probably more than 60%)

My goal, find the point where the "core" start in each list.
A new list come every 5 minutes and will be compared to the previous one. 
What I am interested in is the part that is not the core. In other word I need to retrieve the start of the list up until the core (that was identified) of the previous list.

Efficiency is the key, new list each 5 minutes, but hundreds parallels processing.

Any algo or math way or solution will help :)

I hope I was precise in my request

Comment: what do you mean by core in a list?

Comment: dont see no core - whats your expected output? Do you mean `1518, 4061, 4380, 73160, 83607, 9202, 28812, 40359, 28457, 
 3292, 2678, 8492, 7149, 19417, 7372, 8534, 3889, 11123` that part?

Comment: No attempt? SO is not your free coding service.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation.  [on topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) apply here.
StackOverflow is not a design, coding, research, or tutorial service.

Comment: in a shorter way,  list 1:  8,4,3,5,6,0,1   list 2: 1,3,7,4,3,5,6, here the core is 4,3,5,6. I need to find what changed in list 2 compared to list 1 in the part before the "core", so, find where the "core" start.  here, 8 in first list and 1,3,7 in the second. In real data, list is bigger than 300 elements and the "core" can be compose by 200 elements or more.  i'm not searching a full code, i search a way, algorithm, math, statistics, or a python library which can help me in this task.

Comment: I can take some element in the middle of the first list, search the occurrence in the second and compare elements by elements  on the left of my "mini core" and make it grow until i find a missmatch... but it not seem to be a "smart" way.

Answer (score 0):

This will do it for your samples, did not try it with big lists.The intermediate powersets get gigantic, so might not be the right choice:

```
from itertools import chain,product,islice

l1 = [10318, 6032,1518, 4061, 4380, 73160, 83607, 9202, 28812, 40359, 28457, 
 3292, 2678, 8492, 7149, 19417, 7372, 8534, 3889, 11123, 8415, 5989]

l2 = [5760, 1541, 2085, 637,1518, 4061, 4380, 73160, 83607, 9202, 28812, 40359, 
 28457, 3292, 2678, 8492, 7149, 19417, 7372, 8534, 3889, 11123]

# not really a receipt - but inspired by partition and powerset
# from https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools-recipes
def powerskiptakeset(iterab): 
    """Creates non-empty partitions of a given iterable in existing order 
       from len(1) to len(iterab). 

    Example: 
        [1,2,3,4] --> {(1,), (2,), (3,), (4,), (1, 2), (2, 3), (3, 4),
                       (1, 2, 3), (2, 3, 4),  (1, 2, 3, 4)}"""
    s = list(iterab)
    return set(chain.from_iterable([tuple(islice(s, start, stop))] for 
                               start,stop in product(range(len(s)+1),range(len(s)+1)) 
                               if start < stop))


l1_set = powerskiptakeset(l1)   
l2_set = powerskiptakeset(l2)

core = max( l1_set& l2_set, key=lambda coll: len(coll))

print(list(core))
```

Output:

```
[1518, 4061, 4380, 73160, 83607, 9202, 28812, 40359, 28457, 3292, 
 2678, 8492, 7149, 19417, 7372, 8534, 3889, 11123]
```

---

For a `rage(300)` the resulting set has 45150 elements. You can tune that by f.e. restrincting the powerskiptakeset's to a min lenght 25% of the input iterables length:

```
from itertools import chain,product,islice

def powerskiptakeset_25perc(iterab): 
    """Creates non-empty partitions of a given iterable in order of len(iterab)//4 to len(iterab)

    [1,2,3,4] --> set([(1, 2), (1, 2, 3, 4), (1,), (2,), (3,), (1, 2, 3), (2, 3), (2, 3, 4), (4,), (3, 4)])"""

    s = list(iterab)
    return set(chain.from_iterable([tuple(islice(s, start, stop))] for 
                               start,stop in product(range(len(s)+1),range(len(s)+1)) 
                               if start < stop and stop-start >= len(iterab)//4))

print(len(powerskiptakeset_25perc(range(300))))
```

which drops the amount of tuples in the set down to about 25k.

Comment: Thanks you for the response, i didn't know this method :)

Comment: @Draak what for a method?